# why "find usage" does not work for signals in different subprojects

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals, qt-creator

I am using "Qt 4.8.4" and "QtCreator 3.0" in "Windows 7". I have several subprojects in my application. When i use "find usage" for signals in one subproject, only usage of this signal in current subproject is listed in search result.

How can I find the usage of one signal in all subprojects by the "find usage" tool?

Comment: I have no clue, but just in case, have you tried this with the latest SDK, e.g. Qt 5.4 and 3.1 or something like that?

Comment: @lpapp : No, I only test it with "Qt 4.8.4" and "QtCreator 3.0"  in "Windows 7".
I recently test it with the same Qt in "kubuntu 12" and result is the same.

Comment: I wonder if you could check it just in case so that we would know whether it is an issue with the non-latest versions.

Comment: @lpapp : I test it first thing on Saturday (our first week day)

Comment: I tested it for you and it did not work either.

Answer (score 2):

One could argue that this behavior is acceptable since this is a way to restrict the search to one subproject. Having said that, it would be possible in theory to add an option to look for all the subprojects. I have just created a report for you on their tracker risking that it may be rejected:

[Make the Qt 4 style signal-slot usages easy to find across subprojects](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-13601)

Depending on how you look at it, quick workarounds could be to find the usage of your signal by:

- Search in `All Projects`
- Using the locator and either installing grep or using findstr on Windows:

  ```
  C-K ! grep -rn MySignal MYPATH
  ```

  or

  ```
  C-K ! findstr MySignal MYPATH
  ```

This also may be the reason why they might reject the support of the Qt 4 style signal-slot syntax since it is relatively easy to work around and Qt 4 is inherently not the future, especially in this case where there is some advantages over the new style. You can read more about that in here:

[Signals and Slots in Qt5](http://woboq.com/blog/new-signals-slots-syntax-in-qt5.html)

If your project is nontrivial to port over on to Qt 5, these quick workarounds are relatively acceptable for the time being.

Even if you can port over, you may come across Qt projects opened in your QtCreator instance the code of which is not under your controller. Yet, in those cases, you can use the quick workarounds until they fix it. It is unlikely that the Qt 4 signal-slot syntax will get unused in the upcoming while in all projects.

Comment: Thanks for bug report.

Comment: @AliMofrad: out of curiosity, so you will rather not use this feature then with the workarounds because you put the bounty and selection on the answer that does not give a generic solution?

Comment: Actually "searching in `All Projects`" and the other workarounds is not a solution to me. I have used these tricks before asking the question. Now i have decided to migrate my code to Qt 5.*

Comment: @AliMofrad: Why have you not mentioned in the question what you exactly wanted? Also, how will you migrate all the code out there? IMHO, it is a bit silly idea to try to migrate all the projects out there to Qt 5 just for this little feature/bug in an IDE.